# Collecting generic objects from a list by type parameter

Tags: scala, types, scala-2.11

Suppose we have the following types:

```
sealed abstract class X

case object X1 extends X
case object X2 extends X
case object X3 extends X

class C[XN <: X](val xn: XN)
```

**Problem**: I would like to, given a `import scala.language.existentials; val l: List[C[XN] forSome { type XN <: X }]`, be able to collect all `C[XN]` for chosen `XN <: X`.

This of course doesn't work because there is no way to do a pattern match to coerce elements of `l` into the desired type. My first idea was to define `T` as follows:

```
type T = List[(XN, C[XN]) forSome { type XN <: X}]
```

My hope was that on pattern matching the left side of each tuple by type, I would convince the compiler of the type of the desired second element. This is the function I defined:

```
def collectT[XN : Manifest](t: T): List[C[XN]] = {
  t.collect {
    case (xn: XN, cxn) ⇒
      cxn: C[XN]
    }
}
```

**Compilation Error**: When compiling, I get the following error:

```
[error] /Users/Justin/Code/quantemplate-datapipeline/src/test/scala/random/TypeQuandary.scala:21: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : random.TypeQuandary.C[XN(in method applyOrElse)] where type XN(in method applyOrElse) <: random.TypeQuandary.X
[error]  required: random.TypeQuandary.C[XN(in method collectT)]
[error]         cxn: C[XN]
[error]         ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 22-Jun-2016 15:26:53
```

Is there any way to solve this problem in an elegant way without using `.asInstanceOf`?

Comment: `CanBuildFrom` is not working for you?

Comment: How would you suggest I use it in this case?

Comment: One potential problem is that XN in T is completely disconnected with XN in collectT.

Comment: Changing `XN` in `T` to `XM`, I still get the error that `XN` is not equal to `XM`. Apparently the fact that `xn: XN` is not enough to convince the compiler that `cxn: C[XN]`.